# Add new car-following model in SUMO

Tags: simulation, sumo

I am a new to SUMO (Simulation of Urban Mobility). Can someone help me on how to add new car-following model in SUMO. I have read the official guidance but I cannot find "src" file. The software I use is SUMO 0.26 for Windows (49.36 MB).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the sources which are the third link in the downloads section on http://sumo.dlr.de. Please be aware that sumo 0.27.0 is already out but can currently only be retrieved from http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Downloads. The direct link to the sources is http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sumo/sumo-src-0.27.0.zip?download.
Please use this version because it contains some fixes which apply to the implementation of new car following models.

Answer (score 0):

First, download the SUMO source code from the Downloads section in the following link:http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation_of_Urban_MObility_-_Wiki.

Then, you can follow the steps described in the following link to add a new car following model in sumo: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Developer/How_To/Car-Following_Model.